# FragmentPagerAdapter, Fragments, support.v4 and support.v13

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-support-library, fragmentpageradapter

**My Current Situation**

I am working on an existing app that is using `CustomFragment` derived from `android.app.Fragment`. I want to add a new functionnality with a `ViewPager` which will show my CustomFragments. For that I need to use a `FragmentPagerAdapter`.

**Oooh snap !**

Here I am, importing `android.support.v4.view.ViewPager` and `android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter` to achieve my goal. And now the funny part begins :

- When I try to use my `FragmentPagerAdapter` with my `CustomFragment`, I get the classic error `Type mismatch: cannot convert from android.app.Fragment to android.support.v4.app.Fragment`
- Knowing that I can't change the whole app fragments to `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`, I searched and found that the `android.support.v13.app.FragmentPagerAdapter` was made to use native fragments. Great !
- Not great. When I try to import the v13 FragmentPagerAdapter, I get the error `The import android.support.v13 cannot be resolved`. For the record, I checked in SDKManager what support version is installed : v19.0.1
- I searched again, because of course I can't be the first one with that problem. I found that you can't use `support.v4` and `support.v13` in the same app because v4 is included in v13. And for everyone that encoutered my problem, the solution was to use only `android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter` and `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`

**What to do now ?**

Since I **have to** use `android.app.Fragment` and I can't use only support.v4, I don't know where to go search next. Any help would be highly appreciated !

Comment: You don't have to change the fragment, just import it from the v4 library. Why are you saying that "I can't change the whole app fragments to android.support.v4.app.Fragment" ? Everything should be ok if you use all the classes from v4.

Comment: I'm working on a massive app which is not mine, if there's no other choice I guess I'll change to v4.Fragment everywhere. A coworker told me that V4 Fragment and FragmentManager were kinda slow, need to check about that

Comment: As you did, I lost some time trying to figure out how to use android.app.fragment in my app (with tabs). Well, I can't. I guess the guy who started to write android.app.fragment was fired before he finished his job, and nobody took over. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well that is simply not possible. I went to use support.v4.app.Fragment.

Comment: ? what about the v13 `FragmentPagerAdapter`? It's merely a gradle import.